# QwtLegend inside canvas

Tags: qt, qwt

I want to have an interactive legend inside my canvas, however I'm having trouble getting it to work. I am using qwt6.1.2 and this version no longer has the option to insert the legend as an "ExternalLegend", but instead has the class qwtPlotLegendItem to handle legends inside the canvas. However when I read the docs I see:

> In opposite to QwtLegend the legend item is not interactive.
>
> An external QwtLegend with a transparent background on top the plot
> canvas might be another option with a similar effect.

My question is: how do I show an QwtLegend on top of the plot canvas?

In the documentation for QwtPlot I read:

> Legends, that are not inserted into the layout of the plot widget need
> to connect to the legendDataChanged() signal. Calling updateLegend()
> initiates this signal for an initial update.

I have connected the legendDataChanged signal and triggered it by calling updateLegend(), but now I'm stuck on what to do next. Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work:

```
QwtPlot* plot;

// Attach some plots/histograms to the plot.

MyLegend* legend = new MyLegend(plot);


MyLegend ::MyLegend (QwtPlot * pPlot)
    : m_pPlot(pPlot)
{
   setParent(m_pPlot);
   setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
   connect(m_pPlot, &QwtPlot::legendDataChanged,
                  this, &MyLegend ::LegendDataChanged);

   m_pPlot->updateLegend();
}

void MyLegend ::LegendDataChanged(const QVariant &itemInfo, const QList< QwtLegendData > &data)
{
    updateLegend(itemInfo, data);
}
```